# search engine keyword "sp" not working?

Tags: google-chrome, search

I have defined several search engines in my instance of Chrome.
I tried to define one for StartPage, using keyword "sp" and that one is ignored.
I defined another one to Startpage in french using keyword "s" and it works fine.
If I rename the keyword "sp" to "spt" all is fine.
Do you have the same issue ? Why is that "sp" ignored ??

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any problem on Chrome when using `sp`.

When I enter `sp` in the address-bar and press <kbd>Space</kbd>,
Chrome immediately recognizes the startpage reference:

[image]

Check perhaps your definition of startpage. Mine is:

[image]

To find out if you are using `sp` elsewhere, enter
*Settings > Search engine > Manage search engines*
and type `sp` in the Search field. This may show you any possible conflict.